# JMH gives hectic throughput values

Tags: java, jmh

I'm running [some benchmarks](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/perf/java/rx/schedulers/ComputationSchedulerPerf.java) with JMH and I get hectic throughput values for each iteration, sometimes +/- 50% difference. (i7 4770K, Windows 7 x64, Java 1.8u31, JMH 0.9 - can't upgrade). The benchmarks create quite a lot of garbage due to boxing and unboxing integers and use synchronized blocks heavily. Increasing the iteration run time from 1s to 5s produces less variance.

My questions are:

- How can I discover the source of this variance?
- Why do I get significantly higher throughput values during warmup sometimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a 0.9.1+ version, you should have a look at the `perfasm` profiler that was added to JMH. It allows you to map the assembly of your code to the time spent at each instruction. It will however require you to use a Linux box as it makes use of the `perf` command.

Other than that, your benchmark allows for quite some optimization but I assume this is intended. You do not consume a final result by a black hole but you choose to consume bits of data in between some processing. This approach is quite error-prone and I would therefore recommend you to really look at the assembly code that this procudes no matter what, such that you can tell what it actually is that you are measuring!

Comment: Thanks. It was due to several factors acting at once: large amounts of core-hopping in the benchmark, GC and OS activity.